# Windows 10 reclaimed Win+G. I want it for gadgets

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-10, desktop-gadget

I installed the Windows Gadgets from gadgetsrevived.com on my Windows 10 install. The gadgets work fine, but I'm used to using <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to bring them to the front. It appears that Windows 10 recapitulated that keyboard shortcut for showing the game bar. This is my work computer; I'm fairly certain I don't need the game bar, whatever that is. Can I restore that keyboard shortcut to its original functionality or create some other shortcut to bring the gadgets to the front? <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>?

I suppose I'm open to other light-weight CPU and RAM monitors that I can bring to the front from a keyboard shortcut. I'd love one that sat on my double-high task bar and used enough real estate to be readable.